# Include host in buffer name for all files opened with TRAMP

Tags: tramp

I frequently use TRAMP with emacs to edit files remotely. However, I sometimes have files open from both my production and development server. When I have the same file open on both servers, TRAMP will name the buffers `bar</ssh:stable:>` and `bar</ssh:dev:>`. Is there a way I can get this behavior for all buffers, even if they’re currently only open from one of the servers? For instance, if I’m visiting /foo/bar on only the development server and /baz/qux on only the production server, I would like the buffers to be named `bar</ssh:dev:>` and `qux</ssh:stable:>`, respectively.

Comment: The answer (whatever it will end up being) may entail using the `find-file-hook`, the function `rename-buffer`, and the test described by phils in the related thread, along with my comments underneath his answer -- **Emacs — dired-mode test to determine remote server name / address**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481381/emacs-dired-mode-test-to-determine-remote-server-name-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the following appears to work exactly the way I want as described above. Just put these in your .emacs:

```
(defun add-server-postfix ()
  "Add the name of the connection type and server to the buffer name"
  (if (string-match "^/ssh:.*?:" (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
      (rename-buffer (concat (buffer-name (current-buffer)) "<" (match-string 0 (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))) ">")) nil))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'add-server-postfix)
```